# Move image both left and righ side canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am moving an image using Canvas.

it only moves one side, it's moving right to left all time. but i want it to move both right and left side .

see my code:

```
package com.movingbackground;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MovingBackGround extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Bitmap backGround;

    public MovingBackGround(Context context) {
        super(context);
        backGround = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ab);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        doDrawRunning(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    /**
     * Draws current state of the game Canvas.
     */

    private int mBGFarMoveX = 0;
    private int mBGNearMoveX = 0;

    private void doDrawRunning(Canvas canvas) {

        // decrement the far background
        mBGFarMoveX = mBGFarMoveX - 1;

        // decrement the near background
        mBGNearMoveX = mBGNearMoveX - 4;

        // calculate the wrap factor for matching image draw
        int newFarX = backGround.getWidth() - (-mBGFarMoveX);

        // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
        if (newFarX <= 0) {
            mBGFarMoveX = 0;
            // only need one draw
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);

        } else {
            // need to draw original and wrap
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, newFarX, 0, null);
        }

    }
}
```

now what i want is:
if image moving reach it's corner it should start moving another side.

what i want is exactly: **[see this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2c8j8e_scr-20141210-183228_school)**

this same thing i want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

A very short solution could be replacing the bottom part of your class by this:

```java
    /**
     * Draws current state of the game Canvas.
     */

    private int x = 0;
    private int ix = -1;

    private void doDrawRunning(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, -x, 0, null);

        if (x == 0 || backGround.getWidth() - x == getWidth())
            ix = -ix;

        x += ix;
    }
}
```

**Notes:** This code assumes the background image is larger than your canvas.

Comment: no its not working, image goes left and disappears and don't come again.

Comment: As I said, the code will only work if your image is wider than your canvas `(background.getWidth() > getWidth())`. If you try with a small image it will just slide to the left as you said.